# Merge data with posts in Jekyll

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

I have a directory `_posts` where I store articles.  I also have a data file `_data/teasers.yml` that contains information about articles posted on other sites.  I'm trying to avoid republishing content when I could include a teaser and link back to the original location of the article.

I'd like to combine both teasers and posts so I can loop through them in chronological order.  Is this possible with Jekyll/Liquid?

### Example teaser

```
- title: A harmonious future for profiles and pine
  date: 2017-05-09
  url: https://www.example.com/articles/a-harmonious-future-for-profits-and-pine/
```

### Example template

```
{% assign posts = site.posts %}
{% assign teasers = site.data.teasers %}

# how can I combine these???
{% assign stories = posts | concat: teasers %}

{% for story in stories %}
  {{ story.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

I'm using Jekyll 3.2.x on a mac.

Comment: Roy, can't you just add the teasers to the post front matter itself? Otherwise I don't see how you can link it up easily

Comment: I'm trying to avoid creating an entire page for the post that's just a teaser. I guess i could put the url to the canonical location in the frontmatter and use that instead of the permalink. I'd want to redirect visitors to the page created for the post to the canonical location too, though.

Comment: Ah, do I get you right you want to create pages at runtime from the data file? Like, every data file item will become a page? If that is the case I have some examples for you.

Comment: No, I'm trying to avoid creating a page for each item in my data file and instead link to the original source of the post on another website.  I'd like the teaser for content on other sites to appear in chronological order with teasers for posts created through my jekyll site.